# Map ASP.NET Core Model to Angular 2 (Keep DRY principal)

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

As an ASP.NET Core developer, I just started using Angular 2 for the frontend. And I'm wondering that all articles and books I read yet re-declare their ASP.NET Core Model in JavaScript for Angular 2. This seems not a good idea for me as it violates the DRY principal: Using a ViewModel on the server-side for bandwitch and security purpose looks like best practice for me. So I have to re-declare this ViewModel in JavaScript.

An example could be found in this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1161804/ASP-NET-Core-Angular-EF-Web-API-Using-Template-Pac There

In this case, no seperated ViewModel exists. But to illustrate the situation, let's assume that the follwing class (shortened for readability)  is my ViewModel on the backend:

```
public class Student {  
    [Key]  
    public int Id { get; set}

    [Required]  
    [Display(Name = "Name")]  
    public string Name { get; set}

    [Required]  
    [Display(Name = "Email")]  
    public string Email { get; set}
}
```

Now there exists a manual copy of it in the Angular 2 Component like the following one:

```
export class MyComponent {
    // ...
}

export interface Student {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Email: string;
}
```

I think it would be better to let ASP.NET Core/Visual Studio generate the JavaScript interface from a C# model.

#### What's about validation?

The next level is the validation, where we've the same problem: I need validation rules like the `[Required]` attribute on the server-side. This ensures that only valid data is stored in the database - and no inconsistent data, which may caused by development errors or malicious users, that try to manipulate the requests.

But on the client-side they're required too, so that the user gets feedback about invalid fields. My idea to solve this would be an ajax-handler, which valides the data before sending the form on the server-side, cause this make the redundant validation rules on the client side unnecessary.

Is this best practice, and when yes, how is it done in Angular 2?

Comment: If you think about your backend (C#) as a different project develop by a different team, it would be easier to understand why you have to replicate your class. Another example, is to use an external API (Google API, for example).

Comment: @FabricioKoch It could make sense there. But my idea doesn't make this impossible: My server-side api which is used by Angular 2 could be used in external projects since its independent from the presentation layer. This wouldn't be possible if it's a classic multi-page app, but that's not the case. I can't see why this sould prevent me not to have my .NET models automatically cloned to Angular 2. I see DRY violated if i did not cause every model exist twice with his validation, so changes would require the twice amount of work than necessary. And increased error-prone, too.

Comment: I understand your point. Since you have control about the frontend and backend you have certain freedom to adapt some design pattern. This wouldn't be nice if you were developing only the frontend, for example.

Comment: @FabricioKoch Yes, in this situation, re-defining the model on the client-side seems a valid task for me, too. However, I think there are much projects where this is not the case. And I'm wondering, that I couldn't find any solution to generate Angular 2 models from .NET ones. Sad, since ASP.NET Core provides an excellent way of data-binding on multi-page applications, but not on single-pagers. Not the .NET way of doing things!

Comment: @Lion This question is the #1 reason I don't start developing with Angular. I hate defining the models several times. Each time you make a change you have to remember to replicate it in all layer. Makes no sense in some scenarios, especially if you want a speed development of a project or a LoB app. Have you found a solution? Please share your answer below, you can answer your own questions too!

Comment: @Shimmy I didn't find a real solution, only a workaround by using node.js with TypeScript on the server side. Imho it's not as good as .NET Core, but you can easily share models and also business logic between client and server. On my project I need to parse bbcode/markdown,so I can easily use a single library on both sides, without any issues or duplicated code.

Comment: @Lion, that's what those guys @ Microsoft don't get. They have wonderful languages (such as C# and XAML), but don't provide comprehensive solutions to be able to use their languages and technologies in all platforms. Hopefully web-assembly will be out soon enough. That's when we could say Silverlight is back.